# Java telnet connection to request new tor identity

Tags: java, sockets, connection, telnet, tor

I'm trying to use telnet to request a new identity for tor. From my understanding, you're supposed to send

```
authenticate ""
```

and then if the response is "250 OK" send

```
signal newnym
```

Using this code, I get a response of "null." I have also used several telnet client libraries and get the same kind of results.

```
try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9050);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out.println("authenticate \"\"");
        System.out.println(in.readLine()); //should be 250 but is null

        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You don't have a server socket. For receiving telnet you should have server socket.

Comment: @Iman I tried adding                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber); but not sure what I should make port. if i make it 9050 the port is already binded to tor. If I try making it 9051 it gets stuck on Socket socket =  serverSocket.accept();

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that all commands are case sensitive. So you should be sending them in `UPPER` case (as per documentation).

I also found that a valid new identity request looks like

```
AUTHENTICATE
250 OK
SIGNAL NEWNYM
250 OK
```

Hope that helps!